# Passing object from Spring HandlerInterceptor to Servlet Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

There is a webapp, where every request consumes various external resources. The webapp tracks those consumed resources with request scooped bean. Then HandlerInterceptor's afterCompletion method calls TaskExecutor to store this information in DB. All is fine and dandy, but there goes the requirement to add bandwith consumption as another resource. Counting outgoing response size is a typical task for servlet filter (along with response wrapper and custom stream implementation). So this is done and is also working.

The problem is that I'd like to aggregate two things together. Obviously, I can't pass "bytes sent" to Spring HandlerInterceptor, because filter's doFilter() hasn't completed yet and the amount of bytes sent isn't known when the interceptor runs. So filter must be the place to aggregate all the resource usage and start async task to store it in DB. The problem is: how can I pass data from HandlerInterceptor to Filter. I've tried simple request.setAttribute() but surprisingly it didn't worked.

As a side note: I'm aware of request scooped bean lifecycle and at the handler I'm creating a simple POJO populated with data from scooped bean.

Comment: Did you try do add log traces in both places to see exactly what they see in requests ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah, and this check might just opened a clue. Requests are the same in the sense of content (URL and attributes). However, Filter sees your plain HttpServletRequest while handler is passed Spring Security's SavedRequestAwareWrapper. This shouldn't be anything special, but it appears this wrapper causes some weird things, so this might after all be a valid lead.

Comment: You say requests are the same in sense of URL and attributes. I suppose it is true before you add other attributes in wrapped request. But when back in filter, are the attributes added to wrapped request visibles in original one ?

Comment: Nope. That's why I have asked a question. However, I think I have found a solution. Will do a self-answer as soon as I'll be sure what was causing this in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be quite trival. The app was doing a lot of forward/dispatches as a part of somehwat normal request handling. It turned out that the my filter was called (so far, so good) then another filter down the chain was doing forward/dispatch which then did actual request processing. Default filter setup catches only plain requests and you need additional configuration (web.xml) to also filter forwards/dispatches. I just did that and that solved the problem.